# Why does setting a path of folder and file does not work in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

The script is fetching properties from a file which resides in a folder, which is most of the time but not always the Frontmost window, e.g. the Desktop. But when the script is checking if the file exists at all this always throws an error, although the file is there. Actually the script is fired only when the file is dropped from a location into a FileMaker container. So it IS there!

It boils down to "set fileExists to (containerName & theFile) as alias exists" gives ":Desktoptext2.txt" which seems that the problem is to build the path.

1) What is wrong in the code below?
2) Is there any other way of fetching some properties of a file where the location is not known yet at the time of evaluation?

```
property theFile : "text2.txt"

tell application "Finder"
    try
        -- Gets The Name Of The Front Finder Window If There Is One Opened
        set containerName to name of front Finder window as POSIX file as text
        -- Checks If The File "text2.txt" Exists In That Folder
        -- fileExists Will Be Set To True Or False Depending On The Results
        set fileExists to (containerName & theFile) as alias exists
    on error errMsg number errNum
        -- If Either Of The Previous Commands Throws An Error
        -- This Will Give You An Option To Choose A Folder Where You Think
        -- The File "text2.txt" Is Located
        activate
        set containerName to my (choose folder with prompt "Choose A Folder") as text
    end try
    try
        -- Checks If The File "text2.txt" Exists In The New Chosen Folder
        set fileExists to (containerName & theFile) as alias exists
    on error errMsg number errNum
        -- If "text2.txt" Does Not Exist In This Folder Either, Script Stops Here
        return
    end try
    delay 0.1
    -- If fileExists Is Set To True From Previous Commands 
    if fileExists then
        set fullFilePath to (containerName & theFile) as alias
        set {creation date:creaDate, modification date:modDate, name:fName, displayed name:dName, name extension:nExt, description:descript, URL:fPath} to properties of fullFilePath
        set theText to creaDate & "#" & modDate & "#" & fName & "#" & ¬
            dName & "#" & nExt & "#" & descript & "#" & fPath
        tell current application to (do shell script "echo " & theText & ¬
            ">> $HOME/Desktop/FileProperties.txt")
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: At which line does it exactly throw an error, and what error do you get?

Comment: Your script works for me in Big Sur, but note that depending on the preferences, `name of front Finder Window` may just be the name and not a file reference.

Comment: If you c&p this script and run it in Script Editor it works by showing you a Dialog to select a folder. This is 'cos the error result of the first "Try". Add a "display dialog theFile" between "activate" and "set containerName to my (choose folder with prompt "Choose A Folder") as text" and you see that the filename is present, same when you change that to "display dialog containerName". Test w/ "display dialog (containerName & theFile)" gets ":Desktoptext2.txt" which is not a working path! How has a working path to be defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although a preference can be set to show the POSIX path in the Finder window, normally the name of a Finder window is just that - the **name** of the folder it is opened to.  The `target` property of a Finder window is its file reference, so it is better to use that and coerce to the desired path.

When dealing with the Finder, it can get goofy with POSIX stuff, so it is best to avoid that and just coerce when needed.  An alias can also be used as a shortcut for the `exists` test, since the coercion will fail if the item doesn't exist:

```
property fileName : "text2.txt"

try
    tell application "Finder" to set containerName to target of front Finder window as text
    set filePath to (containerName & fileName) as alias
on error errMsg -- no file or Finder window
    log errMsg
    activate
    try
        set containerName to (choose folder with prompt "Choose A Folder") as text
        set filePath to (containerName & fileName) as alias
    on error errMsg -- no file or cancel
        log errMsg
        return
    end try
end try
log filePath
tell application "Finder" to set {creation date:creaDate, modification date:modDate, name:fName, displayed name:dName, name extension:nExt, description:descript, URL:fPath} to properties of filePath
set theText to creaDate & "#" & modDate & "#" & fName & "#" & ¬
    dName & "#" & nExt & "#" & descript & "#" & fPath
do shell script "echo " & theText & " >> $HOME/Desktop/FileProperties.txt"
```

Comment: AAAAAAWESOME! This works for me! And this also sheds some more light into the why's and hows. Much appreciated!